# deleting an object in a loop that runs through the range of the list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list composed of  [start position, stop position, [sample names with those positions]]

My goal is to remove the duplicates with exact start and stop positions and just add the extra sample to the sample names section.  The problem I'm encountering is that when I delete from the list, I end up with an out of range error, because it's not recalculating the `len(list)` within the loops.

```
for g in range (len(list)) :

    for n in range(len(list)):
    #compares the start and stop position of one line to the start and stop of another line 
          if (list[g][0]==list[n+1][0] and list[g][1]==[n+1][1])
          #adds new sample numbers to first start and stop entry with duplication
          labels1=list[g][2]
          labels2=list[n+1][2]
          labels=labels1+labels2
          list[g][2]=labels
    #now delete the extra line
          del list[n+1]
```

Comment: Another flaw - you end up matching every item with itself, and trying to combine it with itself. You need a "g != n" check.

Comment: You're better off creating a new list with what you want rather than taking an existing list and deleting stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I not sure I understand what you want, but it might be this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for start, stop, samples in L1:
    d[start, stop].extend(samples)
L2 = [[start, stop, samples] for (start, stop), samples in d.items()]
```

Which will take L1:

```
L1 = [ [1, 5, ["a", "b", "c"]], [3, 4, ["d", "e"]], [1, 5, ["f"]] ]
```

and make L2:

```
L2 = [ [1, 5, ["a", "b", "c", "f"]], [3, 4, ["d", "e"]] ]
```

Please note that this does not guarantee the same order of the elements in L2 as in L1, but from the looks of your question, that doesn't matter.

Comment: If the order of elements were important, it would be easy to make a new list of (start, stop) tuples that recorded the order; then your list comprehension that builds L2 could loop over the order-preserving list and thus L2 would be built in the same order.

Comment: By the way, beautiful solution.  I wanted to post an answer but the best I could hope to do would be to re-invent this.

Answer (score 2):

Your loops should not be for loops, they should be while loop with an increment step.  I guess you can just manually check the condition within your for loop (`continue` if it's not met), but a while loop makes more sense, imo.

Comment: Just to clarify - "while g < len(list) :" will react to changes in both g and len(list).

Answer (score 1):

Here is truppo's answer, re-written to preserve the order of entries from L1.  It has a few other small changes, such as using a plain dict instead of a defaultdict, and using explicit tuples instead of packing and unpacking them on the fly.

```
L1 = [ [1, 5, ["a", "b", "c"]], [3, 4, ["d", "e"]], [1, 5, ["f"]] ]


d = {}
oplist = []  # order-preserving list

for start, stop, samples in L1:
    tup = (start, stop)  # make a tuple out of start/stop pair
    if tup in d:
        d[tup].extend(samples)
    else:
        d[tup] = samples
        oplist.append(tup)

L2 = [[tup[0], tup[1], d[tup]] for tup in oplist]

print L2
# prints: [[1, 5, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']], [3, 4, ['d', 'e']]]
```

Comment: This is the solution I used...you guys are amazing.  I was stuck on this problem for three days and this was a great cut and paste solution.  Thanks to everyone for the input!

Comment: @Jill, remember to accept the answer that has helped you most (click on the checkmark-shaped icon below the big number counting the answer's upvotes) -- that's fundamental SO etiquette!

Answer (score 0):

I've just put together a nice little list comprehension that does pretty much what you did, except without the nasty `del` s.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    [1, 1, [2, 3, 4]],
    [1, 1, [5, 7, 8]],
    [1, 3, [2, 8, 5]],
    [2, 3, [1, 7, 9]],
    [2, 3, [3, 8, 5]],
]

data.sort()
print(
    [[key[0], key[1], reduce(add, (i[2] for i in iterator))]
     for key, iterator in groupby(data, lambda item: item[:2])
    ]
)
```